# HTML garbled after using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm downloading a page with urllib2 and loading it into BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import urllib2
baseHTML = 'http://forums.macrumors.com/'
baseForum = 'forumdisplay.php?f=109'
forumHTML = urllib2.urlopen(baseHTML+baseForum).read()
page = Soup(forumHTML)
print forumHTML
print page
```

When printing `forumHTML`, all is well and the html that gets return is completely fine.

However, when printing `page`, the HTML get garbled at this point:

```
<a href="showthread.php?t=324487" id="thread_title_324487">iPhone Tips and Tricks thread</a>
<span class="smallf">o n t "   s t y l e = " w h i t e - s p a c e
```

As you can see, BeautifulSoup add a `>` in the wrong place for some unknown reason.
Here's the same HTML inside `forumHTML`:

```
<a href="showthread.php?t=324487" id="thread_title_324487">iPhone Tips and Tricks thread</a>
<span class="smallfont" style="white-space
```

Why would this happen? I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 64-bit, if that matters.

Comment: I bet that this is because bs4 by default tries to escape chars like '&', '<' and '>' (see [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)). Do you see the same html if you run `print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))`?

Comment: Install `html5lib` and it should work.

Comment: Neither installing `html5lib` nor using `prettify` worked - HTML is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having not found a solution for this for a long time, I decided to re-install BeautifulSoup - that somehow fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem scraping on a Google places page, no > sign was added but I had the same issue with empty spaces introduced in the html code... and reinstalling BeautifoulSoup didn't make it work :)

Anyway, I went back to the BeautifulSoup4 documentation, read about the different HTML parsers that it supports, tried with the Python’s html.parser

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

page = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
```

and problem solved. If you are having this issue probably you'll need to use one of the supported HTML parser.